# Print the execution time on messages Pane?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, execution-plan

How I can print the execution time of each query on messages Pane? For example the `Select * from tbl1` runs for 10 mins then `Select * from tbl2` runs for 15mins and so on..

```
Select * from tbl1
Go
Select * from tbl2
Go
Select * from tbl3
Go
```

Comment: `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;`

Comment: @Mark Surely, but it was just a comment, not an answer, sorry I didn't have time last night to be more thorough.

Comment: @AaronBertand Sorry! Wasn't criticising!

Comment: @Mark it's ok, you're right. For quick stuff it's probably good enough.

Answer (score 5):

DATEDIFF will be useful

```
DECLARE @StartTime1 datetime 

SET @StartTime1 = GETDATE()

select query 1

SELECT ExecutionTimeInMS = DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime1, getdate())

GO
```

similarly do for other queries. @starttime2, 3